# App restarts in samsung mobile when running in background and user click on app icon from suggested app

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m3D3.png)I am stuck with a problem with my android app.

Issue is:-

My application(TP.E) is open and I have navigated from activity1 to activity2 and goes in background by simply clicking on home button. (Remember app is running in background )

a) Now if I open my app again by going into menu and clicking on app icon as shown in image given below, it resume the app from same activity2 running before being put into background.

b) If I click on menu and if then tap on search box it gives me a list of suggested apps which include my app as well, if I click on my app icon from this list it restarts the app and and takes it to activity1 instead.

I want it to be behave as mentioned in case 'a' .

any idea or suggestion will be a great help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Ywd.png)

Answer (score 0):

this problem got solved when i add   android:launchMode="singleTask" to my activity in android. manifest